# Classify elements from a list to another classification with average

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose that we have this class:

```
public enum KindOfPerson
{
    Student, Teacher, ...
}

public class Person
{
    // This contains only numbers between 0 and 1
    public double ScorePercent { get; set; }
    public KindOfPerson Type { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to classify a list by KindOfPerson, but also I'd like to know what is the average of ScorePercent of all the people of the same KindOfPerson.

```
List<List<Person>> groupedLists = peopleList.GroupBy(person => person.Type)
                                                      .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
                                                      .Select(group => group.ToList())
                                                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do it with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)?
You could use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx) and [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#avgSimple) methods.

```
var groupedLists = peopleList.GroupBy(person => person.Type)
                             .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
                             .Select(group => new {
                                 People = group.ToList(),
                                 AverageScore = group.Average(p => p.ScorePercent)
                              })
                              .ToList();
```

#### Update

Assuming you want a list of `Tuple<KindOfPerson, double>`, here you go:

```
var scores = peopleList.GroupBy(p => p.Type)
                       .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.Average(p => p.ScorePercent)))
                       .ToList();
```

Creating a `Dictionary<KindOfPerson, double>` is very similar:

```
var scores = peopleList.GroupBy(p => p.Type)
                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Average(p => p.ScorePercent));
```

Comment: Well, the LINQ function must return a list with contains KindOfPerson and the average

Comment: Please explain a bit more or post some more code. I don't understand what you mean by “another list”.

Comment: @oscar: a list? Did you mean a dictionary? If not, how do you want to store the association?

Comment: @oscar: I updated the answer for `Tuple` case but you can easily change it for `KeyValuePair` or whatever type you want to return the list of.

Comment: Well, the problem that I'm analyzing I think is enough the first option, but if not too much trouble, how would be using a dictionary instead of a list

Comment: @oscar: I added a `Dictionary` sample.